# While reading a file (ifstream), is there any way to direct it to make a new line?

Tags: c++, arrays, input, newline, ifstream

While reading a file (ifstream), is there any way to direct it to make a new line?

For instance, I would like for THIS to happen:

myfile>>array[1]>>array[2]>>endl;

Obviously, the "endl" just isn't allowed. Is there another way to do this?

Edit---thanks for the quick responses guys!

From a text file, I'm trying to store two strings from that file into arrays and then do the same with the next line (or until I desire, using a for loop)

Using strings is important to me as it will make my future program a lot more flexible.

Comment: Since its impossible to do that obviously its not what you want. Describe the effects you are looking for, not the syntax.

Comment: Alright, sorry.  

From a text file, I'm trying to store two strings from that file into arrays and then do the same with the next line (or until I desire, using a for loop).  

I hope I'm coming off as understandable.

Answer (score 4):

Several options:

You can use ignore.

```
myfile >> array[1] >> array[2];
myfile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Or you can read each line into as string stream

```
std::string line;
std::getline(myfile,line);
std::stringstream  stream(line);

stream >> array[1] >> array[2];
```

Please note: Array indexing starts at 0.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::getline` to read a line into a memory stream, then get the two strings from that.

```
while (cin)
{
  string line;
  getline(cin, line);

  stringstream stream;
  stream << line;

  stream >> array[1]>>array[2];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read your two items, then call `myfile.ignore(8192, '\n')`

Comment: Thank you very much Zan, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Where exactly did the 8192 come from though?

Comment: @Vinny: 2 x 4096; it is likely a maximum number of characters to read if no newline is found first.  But given the hint - there's a standard function - you can do the RTFM as well, can't you?

Comment: I guess it is just 'big enough for a line'.

Comment: 8192 is 2 * 4096, and 4096 is a memory page on x86 (it's also 4 KB).

Comment: @dribeas: making assumptions like that will mysteriously break your code one day.

Comment: @yahoo person: So what. Not sure how this relates to strings.

Comment: 8192 is just a large number that is going to be bigger than a line.  I could use max<int> or whatever, but 8192 is easier.

Comment: So?  Do I actually want to read 4 billion bytes if it happened to be a binary file without a '\n' character?  No.  In situations like this I feel its ridiculous to define a constant for max_expected_characters_in_line.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what this question means. Here's a simple way to read all the lines of a file into a vector of strings. It might be easier to do what you want to do if you do this first.

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;

std::string line;
while (std::getline(myFile, line))
    lines.push_back(line);
```

Now you can say `lines[4]` to get the fifth line, or `lines.size()` to find out how many lines there were.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
stringstream stream;
string sLine;
int iLine;

while (cin)
{
  getline(cin, sLine);

  stream << sLine;
  stream >> data[iLine][0] >> data[iLine][1];
}
```

Customized version of an earlier answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work. You keep appending each line to stream without re-setting it to empty. You should declare stream locally inside the loop and it will work.